# Created first package using PyPi. Downloads successfully but is unable to be imported

Tags: import, pip, pypi

I have recently made my own package on PyPi called py3PDB.
It successfully downloads as when installing with pip

```
py -m pip install package_name
```

or

```
pip install package_name
```

It replies with:

```
pip install testPyPack
Collecting testPyPack
  Downloading testPyPack-0.0.1.tar.gz (2.2 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for testPyPack, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: testPyPack
    Running setup.py install for testPyPack ... done
Successfully installed testPyPack-0.0.1
```

However when running a python script importing the package, it replies with

```
import py3PDB

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjects\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import py3PDB
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py3PDB'
```

My package is called py3PDB and i used the video below as a tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhpI6Yhz9_4

Here is the directory for the project

```
PDB
   dist
   py3PDB.egg-info
   pyDialogueBoxes
      __init__.py
      CHANGELOG.txt
      LICENCE.txt
      MANIFEST.in
      README.txt
      setup.py
```

Here is setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
 
classifiers = [
  'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
  'Intended Audience :: Education',
  'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows :: Windows 10',
  'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
  'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
]
 
setup(
  name='py3PDB',
  version='0.0.1',
  description='Dialog Boxes',
  long_description=open('README.txt').read() + '\n\n' + open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
  url='',  
  author='My Name',
  author_email='My Email',
  license='MIT', 
  classifiers=classifiers,
  keywords='Dialog, Box', 
  packages=find_packages(),
  install_requires=['pygame'] 
)
```

Comment: Show the directory structure of your project. Seems like you placed your `__init__.py` in the wrong location. Seeing how you want to `import py3PDB`, then you should move this file into a `py3PDB` directory.

Comment: Check the question again. Just put directory there.

Comment: OK, as I said, the `__init__.py` file seems to be in the wrong location. Maybe show your `setup.py` file as well for confirmation.

Comment: Please include your `setup.py` file.

Comment: Seems to me like the `packages=find_packages(),` line confirms again what I said previously, the `__init__.py` file should be moved to a subdirectory of the directory containing the `setup.py` file. So, since you want to `import py3PDB`, there should be a `py3PDB/__init__.py` file, which according to the directory structure shown in the question would be: `PDB/pyDialogueBoxes/py3PDB/__init__.py`.

Comment: Ahhh ok, i understand. Could you please show me what the entire project should look like?

Comment: Maybe look at this example: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Thank you, I think that helped. Can you please use `py -m pip install pyPDB2` to install. Then import to see if it works?